# How to join multiple records of a model to another model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to set some tags to a question. In `Question` model i use `Tag` as `ForeignKey` -

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class Question(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

What i see in back end for a `Question` can select one `Tag` but i want a single `Question` can select multiple `Tags`.

I am confused what it would be - `ManyToMany` / `OneToMany` /...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ManyToMany` relationship.

As one `Question` can have multiple tags, as well as one `Tag` can be there in multiple questions.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class Question(models.Model):
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Relative queries:

1. Add tag to Question instance as,

   ```
   quest_instance.tags.add(your_tag_instance)
   ```
2. To get all tags for question,

   ```
   quest_instance.tags.all()
   ```
3. Get all questions for particular tag,

   ```
   tag_inst.question_set.all()
   ```

Note: Relative queries may require minor updates.